# Need to track a button with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I need to track a contact form button in Google Tag Manager, but I don't know how to do it. The button's code is the following one:

```
<div class="modalBox" style="transform: translate(-50%, -50%); top: 50%; display: none;"> 

<div class="modalContent">

<a class="closeBtn" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>

<div class="message">

<p class="title">Formulario enviado correctamente</p>

<span class="line"></span>

<p class="subtitle">Contacto enviado con éxito</p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to track the **close button** you have to add a `Just Links` trigger with following rules like: `Click Classes --> contains --> closeBtn`